# Template only for smart pointer

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Hi I am not sure that this is possible since but I thought of asking since there might be better ways of achieving something similar that I am not aware of.
For simplicity lets just consider that `VectorT` is

```
template<class T>
class VectorT: private std::vector<T>`
```

An attempt to what I wanted to have is something along the lines of.

```
namespace detail
{
template<class SmartPtr>
class MyClassVectorBase : public VectorT<SmartPtr>
{
public:
    MyClassVectorBase() = default;

    // all common functions of MyVectorView and MyVector
};
}

using MyClassVectorView = detail::MyClassVectorBase<nonstd::observer_ptr<SomeClass>>;

class MyVector : public detail::MyClassVectorBase<std::unique_ptr<SomeClass>>
{
    // only functions related to the actual owner vector
};
```

What I am hoping is that MyClassVectorBase can be templated only on the smart pointer type and only accept SomeClass.
I thought that it might be possible with a specialization but I got no idea what the syntax for something like that would be

```
template<class T, class SmartPtr>
class MyClassVectorBase : public VectorT<SmartPtr<T>>
{
};

template<SomeClass T, typename SmartPtr>
class MyClassVectorBase : public VectorT<SmartPtr<T>>
{   
};
```

Is something like that even possible ?

**Edited:**
Ok let me try to explain this and the logic behind it. I need to have a VectorT of Foo objects. Only Foo and nothing else.
In one case the class will be the owner of the objects and have a few extra functions.
Since it is the owner it will be class `MyClassVector : public VectorT<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>`
Then I have to somehow operate on these objects but these wont be owned.
The ownership is single and will always outlive the object that I will operate on so no need for `shared_ptr`.
So Then I guess my class will be a "View class" `MyClassVectorView : public VectorT<std::observer_ptr<Foo>>`
Instead of `observer_ptr` it could as well be say raw ptr but the intent is better with it.
Now `MyClassVectorView` will have all identical functions with `MyClassVector` which is why I think that I would be inheriting from it.

To do so I need to have a base class that will accept both `unique_ptr` and `observer_ptr`.
Then I can avoid duplication so long as I can do `MyClassVector : public MyClassVectorView<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>`

The alterantive would be have one class and detect with SFINAE if the template parameter is a unique_ptr and then enable the extra functions. This would avoid the extra inheritance.

Comment: You could use std::is_same to check explicitly against the desired smart pointers

Comment: The above comment or alternatively you can leave the base template undefined and provide a template specialization for SmartPtr<SomeClass>

Comment: You seem to be pretty seriously misusing inheritance here. I wanted to answer this question but it's unclear what you actually want to do. You have `VectorT<T>` that just inherits privately from `std::vector<T>`. Private inheritance is far, far more often wrong than right, so this is a fairly bad sign from the start.

Comment: @MilesRout That was just for simplicity. Regardless, there is nothing wrong with private inheritance of std::vector, plenty wrong with public inheritance of std::vector. I could instead have a vector facade of some sort that is implemented with composition and exposing all the necessary vector functions. In the end that would be identical as what I got now and does not affect the question at all as what I am inheriting from is VectorT.

Comment: There's nothing simple about private inheritance of `std::vector`, and there is plenty wrong with it. You almost certainly shouldn't be using any inheritance in this problem at all. Inheritance has confused and muddled your code and it's unclear what you're trying to do. It sounds like what you actually want is just some templated free functions - I don't see why you need any classes at all here.

Comment: Inheritance is almost always an antipattern in C++. There are very few situations where inheritance is the right solution. Although it's difficult to tell what you're actually trying to do, I suspect you don't need inheritance.

Comment: Sure but this again does not affect this question. Lets say I swap the inheritance with composition. I think its clear of what I am trying to achieve but there might be some more info here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/041cea7045fd1f2b. How would you avoid duplication between the 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about what you want to obtain but I suspect that you need template template parameters.

I suppose you could declare (but not define) `MyClassVectorBase` as receiving a single template typename parameter

```
template <typename>
class MyClassVectorBase;
```

and next define a specialization template-template based; something like

```
template <template<typename...> class SmartPtr, typename Foo>
class MyClassVectorBase<SmartPtr<Foo>> : public VectorT<SmartPtr<Foo>>
{
public:
    MyClassVectorBase() = default;

    void doSomething(){}
    void doSomething2(){}
};
```

If `Foo` isn't a template parameter, but is the `Foo` `struct`, you can write

```
template <template<typename...> class SmartPtr>
class MyClassVectorBase<SmartPtr<Foo>> : public VectorT<SmartPtr<Foo>>
{
public:
    MyClassVectorBase() = default;

    void doSomething(){}
    void doSomething2(){}
};
```

Your example modified and integrated (with a `main()` and a dummy `observer_ptr`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

namespace nonstd
 {
   template <typename T>
   struct observer_ptr
    { };

 }

template <class T>
class VectorT
{
public:
    // expose nececssary functions

private :
    std::vector<T> container_;
};

struct Foo{
    double x;
};

template <typename>
class MyClassVectorBase;

// this class should only accept smart pointers of Foo
template <template<typename...> class SmartPtr, typename Foo>
class MyClassVectorBase<SmartPtr<Foo>> : public VectorT<SmartPtr<Foo>>
{
public:
    MyClassVectorBase() = default;

    void doSomething(){}
    void doSomething2(){}
};

using MyClassVectorView = MyClassVectorBase<nonstd::observer_ptr<Foo>>;

class MyVector : public MyClassVectorBase<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>
{
    // function only for this class but still inheriting all MyClassVectorBase stuff
};

int main ()
 {
 }
```

Comment: That was definitely on the right track and most certainly worked so I am accepting it as correct. I did have issues though with my own classes needed to add the deleter for the unique_ptr. In the end this was easier, even though I am not aware if there are any issues with it `template<template<class...> class SmartPtr>
class MyVector : public VectorT<SmartPtr<Foo>>
{
public:
 void doSomething1() {}
 void doSomething2() {}
};

MyVector<std::unique_ptr> v1;
MyVector<nonstd::observer_ptr> v2;`